# Segmentation Fault during Vector_2 destruction after multiple updates

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, computational-geometry, cgal

I have written a program that uses *CGAL::Vector_2* objects with the *CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel* for data representation.

Basically, the code has an struct containing a *CGAL::Vector_2* which I update during the execution by adding to it numerous other CGAL vectors. The problem is that **depending on how many additions I perform** to the vector within the structure, later, during the object deletion the following *segmentation fault* is produced:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000409693 in CGAL::Lazy_rep_3GAL::Interval_nt > >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Construct_vector_2 >, CGAL::Cartesian_converter, CGAL::Simple_cartesian >, CGAL::NT_converter > >, CGAL::Return_base_tag, int, int>::~Lazy_rep_3() ()

I have been able check to empirically that **the fault is produced every time I perform more than 47961 additions to the vector** inside the struct. **If I do less, the object is destructed properly** and the program finishes correctly.

I tried to track the problem with GDB, but this only lead me to see that the problem was occurring during the vector deletion.

At this point I am wondering if I screwed up somewhere in my code or if this could just be a bug on the library.

Here is a copy of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// CGAL library functions & classes
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Vector_2.h>  

// NULL VECTOR definition
#define NULL_VECTOR CGAL::NULL_VECTOR

// SCENE ORIGIN definition
#define SCENE_ORIGIN CGAL::ORIGIN

// CGAL types definition
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Rep;
typedef CGAL::Vector_2<Rep> Vector;


// Structure that stores internally a CGAL::Vector<2> object
// which is initialized as CGAL::NULL_VECTOR
struct foo
{
    // Attributes
    std::string id;
    Vector vector;

    // Constructor
    foo() : id("foo"), vector(NULL_VECTOR) 
    {
        std::cout << "[ foo() ]: Creating foo object at " << this << std::endl;
        this->print_info("foo()");
    }

    // Copy constructor
    foo(const foo& f) : id("foo_copy"), vector(NULL_VECTOR)
    {
        std::cout << "[ foo(const foo&) ]: Coping foo object at " << &f << " to foo object at " << this << std::endl;
        this->print_info("foo(const foo&)");
    }

    // Destructor
    ~foo()
    {
        std::cout << "[ ~foo() ]: Deleting foo object at " << this << std::endl;
        this->print_info("~foo()");
    }

    void print_info(std::string func_name)
    {
        std::string func_id = "[ " + func_name + " ]: ";
        std::cout << func_id << "foo.id memory position = " << &(this->id) << std::endl
                  << func_id << "foo.id value = " << this->id << std::endl
                  << func_id << "foo.vector memory position: " << &(this->vector) << std::endl
                  << func_id << "foo.vector value: ";
        printf("(%.2f, %.2f)\n\n", CGAL::to_double(this->vector.x()) ,CGAL::to_double(this->vector.y()));
    }
};


// foo_function receives by copy a foo object and through a loop
// will increase repeatedly the value of foo's inner vector.
void foo_func(foo f, int iterations)
{
    std::cout << "[ foo_function(foo) ]: Started" << std::endl; 
    for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<iterations; j++)
        {
            printf("%c[s\r[ foo_funtion(foo) ]: Running iteration (i=%d,j=%d)%c[u",033,i,j,033);
            Vector update(i,j);
            f.vector = f.vector + update;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n[ foo_function(foo) ]: Finished\n" << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int iterations = 219; 
    //219 is the fist value for iterations
    //that produces the seg fault

    if (argc > 1)
        iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Creating a foo object
    foo f;

    // Calling foo_function to update it inner vector 'iteration' times
    std::cout << "[ main() ]: Calling foo_function()\n" << std::endl;
    foo_func(f, iterations);
    std::cout << "[ main() ]: Returned from foo_function()\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the line I used to compile it:

> g++ -frounding-math -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -lCGAL -lmpfr -lgmp -lboost_thread cgal_vector_error.cpp

As indicated in the previous line, it requires the following libraries to run:

- CGAL
- MPFR
- GMP
- Boost.Thread

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Did you try increasing the size of the stack? Does it work better with `-DCGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL`?

Comment: Ah, yes, with -DCGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL it still uses lazy numbers instead of lazy objects, so it may even be worse. Something like `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>` (maybe wrapped in a `Filtered_kernel`) would avoid the whole thing. Calling `CGAL::exact(f.vector)` once in a while should help as well. Basically CGAL keeps a tree of your additions to avoid doing the exact computation if possible, and the tree gets too large in this case.

Comment: The `-DCGAL_DONT_USE_LAZY_KERNEL`flag during code compile doesn't seem to change anything.
The, I increased the size of the stack by calling [setrlimit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Limits-on-Resources.html) from my code and that avoided the _segmentation fault_ occurrence.
However, I don't quite get why I should be running out of stack. I am not doing recursive calls or storing an unreasonable amount of objects in the stack.

Comment: Oh, I see... So it doesn't perform the computation, but it stores the operations until the actual value is needed.
I cannot use another type of kernel as in my real code I am using the [CGAL::do_intesect](http://goo.gl/dZdnrd) function which [requires that type of kernel in order to perform correctly](http://goo.gl/n07Xgw).
What is the efect of the CGAL::exact function you mention? I couldn't find it documentation. Does it forces the vector to perform  the real computation?

Comment: The lazy kernel is mostly undocumented, but yes, CGAL::exact(obj) should force the exact computation of obj (and prune the now useless tree of operations). Note that `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>` is exact so would be fine for use with `do_intersect`.